# tensorflow sample sizes for epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a dataset of 50000 items: reviews & sentiment (positive or negative)

I distributed 90% to the training set and the rest to the testing set.

My question is, if I run 5 epochs on the training set that I have, shouldn't each epoch load 9000 instead of 1407?

```
# to divide train & test sets
test_sample_size = int(0.1*len(preprocessed_reviews))  # 10% of data as the validation set

# for sentiment
sentiment = [1 if x=='positive' else 0 for x in sentiment]

# separate data to train & test sets
X_test, X_train = (np.array(preprocessed_reviews[:test_sample_size]), 
                   np.array(preprocessed_reviews[test_sample_size:])
)

y_test, y_train = (np.array(sentiment[:test_sample_size]), 
                   np.array(sentiment[test_sample_size:])
)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token='<OOV>')  # for the unknown words
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)

vocab_count = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1  # +1 is for padding


training_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)  # tokenizer.word_index to see indexes
training_padded = pad_sequences(training_sequences, padding='post')  # pad sequences with 0s 
training_normal = preprocessing.normalize(training_padded)  # normalize data

testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)  
testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences, padding='post')  
testing_normal = preprocessing.normalize(testing_padded)  


input_length = len(training_normal[0])  # length of all sequences


# build a model
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_count, output_dim=2,input_length=input_length))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(63, activation='relu'))  # hidden layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))  # hidden layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # output layer

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_normal, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
1407/1407 [==============================] - 9s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4992
Epoch 2/5
1407/1407 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5030
Epoch 3/5
1407/1407 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4987
Epoch 4/5
1407/1407 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5024
Epoch 5/5
1407/1407 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5020
```

Sorry I'm quite new to tensorflow, I hope someone could help out!

Comment: each epoch will train on whole train dataset i.e of 45000 in your case. 1407 will be total batches considering the batch size of 32(default value)

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde oh I see.. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have around 50,000 datapoints, distributed with 90/10 ratio (train/test), that means that ~45,000 will be the training data, and remaining 5000 will be for testing.
When you call a fit method, Keras has the default parameter for batch_size set to 32(you can always change that to 64, 128..)
So the number 1407 tells you that the model needs to do 1407 feedforward and backpropagation steps, before one full epoch is completed(**because 1407 * 32 ~ 45,000**).